# Обновление v-if при смене route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

У меня на сайте есть компонент  боковой панели, содержащий контекстные ссылки:

```
<template>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" v-if="this.$router.currentRoute.name === 'PersonDetails'">
      <router-link
        :to="{ name: 'PersonHistory', params: { id: this.$router.currentRoute.params.id } }"
        >история изменений карточки</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavigationSidebar',
};
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что при клике на ссылку в sidebar сам переход происходит на новый route, но не происходит изменения отрисовки компонента, хотя условия в v-if'ах уже должны были скрыть одни пункты и показать другие.

В сети в похожих случаях встречаются рекомендации использовать beforeRouteUpdate, но непонятно, какой хук жизненного цикла компонента вызвать. (Ну и логично, что можно watch вспомнить — проблема та же: что вызывать при изменениях?)

Также [видел рекомендацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517368/5752652) использовать key для router-view, попробовал её, а также наугад попробовал на уровне template компонента задать — ни то, ни то не помогло. :(

Перешерстил документацию, [натолкнулся](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) на любопытный вариант с `v-bind:is` но увы, там нельзя указать строку, нужен компонент:

```
  computed: {
    currentTabComponent() {
      return this.$router.currentRoute.name;
    },
  },
```

поэтому выдаёт ошибку '[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?'

Что можно в данном случае сделать? Vue 2.6.11, типовой router в режиме history.

Comment: Натолкнулся на интересную [статью по способам re-render](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) плюс на so такой же [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755228/5752652), сижу пробую.

Comment: У Вас проблема в том, что по разным роутам отображается один и тот же компонент?

Comment: Да, проблема именно в этом: по разным роутам один и тот же компонент, точнее компонент и ожидается один и тот же, но в зависимости от разных роутов должен отрисовываться иначе.

Comment: Весь пример для воспроизведения сводится по факту к строке `<navigation-sidebar :key="currentComponentKey"></navigation-sidebar>`, больше там ничего нет.

Comment: Да, иногда такие проблемы решается методом "тыка") . И насоветовать можно много разного. Попробуйте текущий роут поместить в computed : `curRoute() return this.$router.currentRoute.name` . И уже в v-if - сравнивайте со значением computed

Comment: @Дмытрык Кстати, логичная идея! Не взлетело, та же самая ошибка, но пока писал подумал почему я использую this.$router а не this.$route -- и вуаля! -- всё взлетело без шаманских танцев.

Answer (score 2):

Ну надо же... всё совершенно спокойно работает если записать так:

```
<li class="nav-item" v-if="this.$route.name === 'PersonDetails'">
```